# How to create a 9x9 grid more efficiently? (Python, Tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am creating a 9x9 grid for a sudoku puzzle generator.
So far I have created 9 variables for the first row of frames, and have given the 9 variables grid rows / columns. The code i am using is below.

I need a more efficient way of doing this because i have to create 81 of these cells for the grid. How can i do it more efficiently/better? Please help!

code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Sudoku')
root.geometry('1000x1000')

# create all of the main containers
center = Frame(root, bg='white', width=900, height=900, padx=3, pady=3)

# layout all of the main containers
root.grid_rowconfigure(9, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(9, weight=1)
center.grid(row=1, sticky="nsew")

# create the center widgets
center.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
center.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

cell1 = Frame(center, bg='white', highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1, width=100, height=100,  padx=3,  pady=3)
cell2 = Frame(center, bg='white', highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1, width=100, height=100,  padx=3, pady=3)
cell3 = Frame(center, bg='white', highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1, width=100, height=100,  padx=3, pady=3)
cell4 = Frame(center, bg='white', highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1, width=100, height=100,  padx=3, pady=3)
cell5 = Frame(center, bg='white', highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1, width=100, height=100,  padx=3, pady=3)
cell6 = Frame(center, bg='white', highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1, width=100, height=100,  padx=3, pady=3)
cell7 = Frame(center, bg='white', highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1, width=100, height=100,  padx=3, pady=3)
cell8 = Frame(center, bg='white', highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1, width=100, height=100,  padx=3, pady=3)
cell9 = Frame(center, bg='white', highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1, width=100, height=100,  padx=3, pady=3)

#create first row of grid

cell1.grid(row=0, column=0)
cell2.grid(row=0, column=1)
cell3.grid(row=0, column=2)
cell4.grid(row=0, column=3)
cell5.grid(row=0, column=4)
cell6.grid(row=0, column=5)
cell7.grid(row=0, column=6)
cell8.grid(row=0, column=7)
cell9.grid(row=0, column=8)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use a for loop? `for i in range(81):`

Comment: It's a good question, but there are excellent answers elsewhere.  Search for a tutorial on nested lists (Python) or 2-D arrays (tkinter).  Stack Overflow is not the place for a tutorial on a seminal programming topic.

Answer (score 3):

A loop for the rows, and a loop for the columns. Store references to the widgets in a dictionary:

```
cells = {}
for row in range(9):
    for column in range(9):
        cell = Frame(center, bg='white', highlightbackground="black",
                     highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1,
                     width=100, height=100,  padx=3,  pady=3)
        cell.grid(row=row, column=column)
        cells[(row, column)] = cell
```

With the above, you can reference any widget via the `cells` dict. For example, to set the cell in row 3, column 4 (counting from zero) to red you could do this:

```
cells[(3,4)].configure(background="red")
```

Comment: tried that but it came up with a syntax error

Comment: Does `cells = dict()` have any superiority over `cells = list()` in this particular case? I usually find it easier to use list when `grid` layout is used.

Comment: @Nae: any superiority is purely subjective. I personally find dictionaries easier to use than lists of lists.

Comment: @TomConboy: there is no syntax error in the code. I can literally cut and paste the code into a small program and it works without modification.  It does, however, assume a different importing style than you use. I'll update it to use your importing style, though it's not the preferred way.

Comment: right. I used this code and it came up with an error. I'm not sure what the code you suggested was supposed to replace? This project is way above my level of coding, although ive got to do it for school. This is the code i ran: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i5w0wm9zvesq09y/New%20Text%20Document.txt?dl=0

Comment: @TomConboy: this code isn't supposed to _replace_ anything. It's an example for you to learn from. Don't copy and paste the code, learn the concept and apply it to your code.